# Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install, npm-publish

I am trying to create few react components with few custom changes as package and publish into npm so that other projects can use them by importing package.

My package is "sample-testing" available at (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sample-testing).

Using "webpack" and "babel loader" to traslate the jsx files.

Getting below error when I tried to use that component from this package.

**Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.**

This error is coming only when I used material ui components inside package but not with regular html components.

**.babelrc**

```
  {
 "presets": ["react", "env", "stage-0"]
  }
```

**wepack.config.js**

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: {
    TButton: "./src/TButton.jsx"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("lib"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**TButton.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

class TButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Standard" />;
  }
}

export default TButton;
```

Here is the codesandbox link (https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-mcclintock-xtkh6?file=/src/index.js) to replicate the error which I am getting in my project when I used in my project.
Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 21):

One reason could be you are importing `useEffect` from the wrong place (probably the IDE did it)

Wrong

```
import {useEffect} from "react/cjs/react.production.min";
```

OK

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error when there is an incompatible react version applied in the runtime. Had to change react and react-dom versions in the main package.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but when using rollup. I solved it by moving `react` and `react-dom` to `peerDependencies` in package.json

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason for this error is this  import { useState } from "react/cjs/react.production.min";
Please import from 'react'

Answer (score 0):

dsa

"peerDependencies": {
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"
},

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).